Cannot Create Token ID from Transaction with REST API on CyberSource
I'm having difficulty generating a token ID from the Transaction section on CyberSource sandbox environment via the REST API.
On CyberSource's UI, I can create it through CyberSorce's documentation. But doing this through the API is very difficult; I haven't found any documentation that mentions this.
In the request body sent to CyberSource, we only have the following information: merchantReferenceCode, requestID, requestToken, authorizationCode, reconciliationID, and payment_id. I would like to ask you to confirm that if I only have the above information, Can I create a token ID on CyberSource?
If possible, please let me know that CyberSource has documents about this.
Thank you very much for your support. I really appreciate your help.
I was tried create it on Postman and following document from CyberSource and Postman.
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2960117/S17m1riA#intro
https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thank you for your interest in my article. I couldn't find any request that could create a token ID with the information I have (merchantReferenceCode, requestID, requestToken, authorizationCode, reconciliationID, and payment_id). Neither CyberSource nor Postman's documentation mentions this.

Find the below API request to create a token in the API
{
  "clientReferenceInformation": {
    "code": "TC50171_3"
  },
  "processingInformation": {
    "actionList": [
      "TOKEN_CREATE"
    ],
    "actionTokenTypes": [
      "customer",
      "paymentInstrument",
      "shippingAddress"
    ]
  },
  "paymentInformation": {
    "card": {
      "number": "41111xxxxxxx1111",
      "expirationMonth": "12",
      "expirationYear": "2031",
      "securityCode": "123"
    }
  },
  "orderInformation": {
    "amountDetails": {
      "totalAmount": "102.21",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "billTo": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "address1": "1 Market St",
      "locality": "san francisco",
      "administrativeArea": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94105",
      "country": "US",
      "email": "test@cybs.com",
      "phoneNumber": "4158880000"
    },
    "shipTo": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "address1": "1 Market St",
      "locality": "san francisco",
      "administrativeArea": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94105",
      "country": "US"
    }
  }
}

For more info visit the official Cypersource page here
